# How to derive receiver noise figure/input noise floor

Tags: rf, receiver, microwave, noisefloor

When calculating the noise figure for a receiver, assuming the IF bandwidth is narrower than the input RF bandwidth, do you use the narrower IF bandwidth to derive the receiver noise figure?  Also, when calculating the input noise floor power level at the receiver input, do you use the wider input RF bandwidth in said calculation, or the narrower IF bandwidth since that is what the receiver ultimately outputs?  If you use the IF bandwidth for said noise floor calculation, would that imply that your noise floor power level will drop after the RF bandwidth is reduced by filtering, at least due to the contribution of B in kTB? (Assume a lossless filter)

Answer (score 1):

The noise figure of any stage is independent of the bandwidth. Both the reference noise and the input added noise are scaled by the same stage bandwidth.

The input noise floor is usually measured per Hz, spectral density, that is independent of bandwidth.

It's only when we get to the back end and start thinking about Eb/N0 and specific modulation schemes or recovered signal properties that we include the bandwidth.